# Is it possible to use <router-link> injected with javascript (backticks)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a form that checks if the email already exists in the database. If the email does exist, I want to redirect the user to a different route and pass the email as a parameter so that I can pre-fill the email inputfield on the `/login` route.

Currently I am doing this with a simple `<a>` tag, like so (without sending the email as a parameter):

```
this.setErrorFor(
  emailFormControlInner,
  `<span>Dit e-mailadres is al in gebruik.. <a href="/app/auth/sign-in">Inloggen?</a> </span>`
);
```

I would like to do something like this to pass the email as a parameter.

```
this.setErrorFor(
  emailFormControlInner,
  `<span>Dit e-mailadres is al in gebruik.. <a><router-link :to="{ name: 'loginScreen', params: { email: this.email } }">Inloggen?</router-link></a>`
);
```

Is that at all possible? And if so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Why do you not interpolate the final content in node when sending the link ? Just compute a variable and input it alone rather than a whole Vue component.

Comment: Editing the DOM like that is a very bad idea; your Vue templates should already contain all the components necessary to reflect all possible app states. In this case you need a basic data structure to hold the text and the link properties, then use conditional rendering in your template to display the necessary components.